# FCM Getting NOT REGISTERED on some android devices

Tags: android, push-notification

I m using FCM to send notification on an android device. getting notifications in some devices and in some devices there is an error. {\"error\":\"NotRegistered\"}

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
        .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }
            val token = task.result?.token
        })
```

Also, onNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

The official [firebase documentation][1] says:

> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the client app unregisters with FCM.
> - If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
> - If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.

Usually you will receive this error in case when backend application sends a push with an expired token.

Comment: Already tried all the things. But no success. It's a fresh install and getting the fcm token. How can I refresh the FCM token?

Comment: @Arahim try to print the token exactly after running the app , and then you will be sure that the token is correct

Comment: Also onNewToken is not getting called.